# Why is my countdown not stopping at 0?

Tags: javascript

```js
//Not finished -- disregard
function evaluate() {
  var cdate = new Date();
  var cday = cdate.getDay();
  var chr = cdate.getHours();
  var cmin = cdate.getMinutes();
  var csec = cdate.getSeconds();
  //Luni
  if (cday === 1) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 100, "countdown")
  }
  //Marti sau Miercuri
  if ((cday === 2) || (cday === 3)) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
  //Joi
  if (cday === 4) {
    countDown(0, 0, 0, 100, "countdown")
  }
  //Vineri sau Sambata
  if ((cday === 5) || (cday === 6)) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
  //Duminica
  if (cday === 0) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
}

function countDown(sec, min, hour, day, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Urmatorul eveniment este in " + day + " zile " + hour + " ore " + min + " minute " + sec + " secunde.";
  if ((sec === 0) && (min > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
  }
  if ((sec === 0) && (min === 0) && (hour > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = 59;
    hour = hour - 1;
  }
  if ((sec === 0) && (min === 0) && (hour === 0) && (day > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = 59;
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }

  if ((min < 0) && (day > 0)) {
    min = 59;
    day = day - 1;
  }
  if ((min < 0) && (day === 0) && (day > 0)) {
    min = 59;
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }

  if ((hour < 0) && (day > 0)) {
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }
  //Here is the deadline if
  if ((day === 0) && (hour === 0) && (min === 0) && (sec < 0)) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    elem.innerHTML = "Evenimentul este in decurs!";
  }
  sec--;
  var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + sec + ',' + min + ',' + hour + ',' + day + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
}
evaluate();
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

My JavaScript is not working. When all values hit 0, the timer should clear.

My target is: evaluate date --> display --> reset.

```
if ((day === 0) && (hour === 0) && (min === 0) && (sec < 0)) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?
I've set up a code snippet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try: `window.clearTimeout(timer);`

Comment: Also, you need to declare `time` in the global scope

Comment: Well, you are calling setTimeout again, even after you did clearTimeout. So what did you expect? Maybe add `return;` after `clearTimeout...`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now! I am sorry if the question was quite useless, but I have just started learning JS! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition to `sec <= 0` and reduce the seconds inside `else` statement

```
if ((day === 0) && (hour === 0) && (min === 0) && (sec <= 0)) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    elem.innerHTML = "Evenimentul este in decurs!";
  }else{
    sec--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + sec + ',' + min + ',' + hour + ',' + day + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the function when you have cleared the timer and output the message (with `return`).

Also the message should be output to the `element` not the `elem` element.

Finally, the *timer* value should be retained across function calls, so make it global. As long as timer is 0 it will work, but if you have more timers, the assigned timer value will be non-zero, and you will not be able to clear it unless you have this value retained outside of the function.

This works:

```js
var timer;
 
//Not finished -- disregard
function evaluate() {
  var cdate = new Date();
  var cday = cdate.getDay();
  var chr = cdate.getHours();
  var cmin = cdate.getMinutes();
  var csec = cdate.getSeconds();
  //Luni
  if (cday === 1) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 100, "countdown")
  }
  //Marti sau Miercuri
  if ((cday === 2) || (cday === 3)) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
  //Joi
  if (cday === 4) {
    countDown(0, 0, 0, 100, "countdown")
  }
  //Vineri sau Sambata
  if ((cday === 5) || (cday === 6)) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
  //Duminica
  if (cday === 0) {
    countDown(5, 0, 0, 0, "countdown")
  }
}

function countDown(sec, min, hour, day, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Urmatorul eveniment este in " + day + " zile " + hour + " ore " + min + " minute " + sec + " secunde.";
  //Here is the deadline if
  if ((sec === 0) && (min > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
  }
  if ((sec === 0) && (min === 0) && (hour > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = 59;
    hour = hour - 1;
  }
  if ((sec === 0) && (min === 0) && (hour === 0) && (day > 0)) {
    sec = 59;
    min = 59;
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }

  if ((min < 0) && (day > 0)) {
    min = 59;
    day = day - 1;
  }
  if ((min < 0) && (day === 0) && (day > 0)) {
    min = 59;
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }

  if ((hour < 0) && (day > 0)) {
    hour = 23;
    day = day - 1;
  }
  if ((day === 0) && (hour === 0) && (min === 0) && (sec < 0)) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML = "Evenimentul este in decurs!";
    return;
  }
  sec--;
  timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + sec + ',' + min + ',' + hour + ',' + day + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
}
evaluate();
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```